# can't retrieve modified checked items from treeview - only shows state at load

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, treeviewitem, radtreeview

I'm populating a treeview in c# asp.net and have bound data to it, all well and displays as it should. my problem now is that i'm looking to save any modifications to the checkboxes i.e if a user clicks an additional box and saves but i the checked state will stay false.

here's what i have so far which iterates through what was initially loaded and not what has been changed, I've tried many variations but haven't managed to get it working - anyone any ideas??

```
public void saveCheckedItems()
{

    if (treeListItems.CheckedNodes.Count > 0)
    {
        IList<RadTreeNode> allNodes = treeListItems.GetAllNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < allNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            RadTreeNode node = (RadTreeNode)allNodes[i];
            string fileid = node.Value.ToString();
            if (node.Checked == true)
            {
                if (fileid.Length == 12)
                {
                    saveTreeChanges(Page.Request.QueryString["ID"], fileid,connectionStr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

edit -

creating treeview as follows

```
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="treeListItems" runat="server" CheckBoxes="True" Height="320px"
                            TriStateCheckBoxes="true" CheckChildNodes="true" Skin="WebBlue" CssClass="table table-bordered" OnNodeDataBound="RadTreeView1_NodeDataBound" >
                        </telerik:RadTreeView>
```

binding data like this

```
public void loadTreeList()
        {
            DataTable dt = treeMan.getTreeList(connectionStr);
            treeListItems.DataTextField = "Description";
            treeListItems.DataValueField = "FieldID";
            treeListItems.DataFieldID = "FieldID";
            treeListItems.DataFieldParentID = "ParentID";
            treeListItems.DataSource = dt;
            treeListItems.DataBind();
            treeListItems.ExpandAllNodes();
        }
```

in the example im testing its a 3 tier tree and one element is checked on third tier. When i click more items only this already checked item is visible in the list

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: When exactly in the page's life cycle do you call the `saveCheckedItems()` method?

Comment: @alex  i call it on updatebtn_click

Comment: Is `loadTreeList` called on each `Page_Load`?

Comment: hi alex yes it is just thought on that as well but i then put it behind !Page.IsPostBack and now it will not load after pressing the update btn control

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void saveCheckedItems()
{
    IList<RadTreeNode> nodeCollection = treeListItems.CheckedNodes;
    foreach (RadTreeNode node in nodeCollection)
    {
        string fileid = node.Value.ToString();
        if (fileid.Length == 12)
        {
            saveTreeChanges(Page.Request.QueryString["ID"], fileid, connectionStr);
        }
    }
}
```

The only way to preserve the state of the checked nodes is to put them into an object which persists between page postbacks. I recommend you to use a cookie or the [ASP.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx). Consider the example in the following comment: http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/treeview/save-the-expanded-state-of-the-treenodes-when-the-treeview-is-being-bound-upon-each-postback.aspx#1603151.

Comment: exact same issue, despite clicking more items the list stays the same?